# Паттерн проектирования Factory как добавить метод

Tags: java

Изучаю Паттерн проектирования Factory
Вот один из примеров его использования, они практически везде однотипные:

```
public interface Coffee {
  void grindCoffee();
  void makeCoffee();
  void pourIntoCup();
}
public class Americano implements Coffee {
  public void grindCoffee() {
    System.out.println("перемалываем кофе Americano");
  }
  public void makeCoffee() {
    System.out.println("перемалываем кофе Americano");
  }
  public void pourIntoCup() {
    System.out.println("наливаем кофе Americano");
  }
}
public class CoolCoffe implements Coffee{
  public void grindCoffee() {
    System.out.println("перемалываем кофе CoolCoffe ");
  }
  public void makeCoffee() {
    System.out.println("перемалываем кофе CoolCoffe ");
  }
  public void pourIntoCup() {
    System.out.println("наливаем кофе CoolCoffe ");
  }
  public void сoll() {
    System.out.println("охлаждаем кофе CoolCoffe ");
  }
}
public class MyCoffe {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coffee myCoffee;
    switch(type) {
      Americano:
        myCoffee= new Americano();
      CoolCoffe:
        myCoffee= new Americano();
   }
   ...
   myCoffee.pourIntoCup();
   myCoffee.сoll(); //Error
 }
}
```

1. Везде приводится этот switch, но как-то с ним не красиво получается, а если будет 20-30 классов. Как от него избавиться,
2. Если мне надо добавить метод, только в один класс (например public void сoll()), он больше ни где не будет нужен. Можно как-то это сделать, не прописывая его в interface Coffee? Как сделано в примере он не доступен.

Comment: Суть полиморфизма такова, что когда в методе main создаётся экземпляр Coffee, то предполагается что кроме методов этого интерфейса другие методы классов наследников не будут вызываться, потому что это методы детализации. Объекты надо создавать напрямую без switch. В частности метод coll() должен вызываться из переопределенных методов интерфейса Coffee внутри класса CoolCoffe.

Comment: можете пример сделать, чтобы я его как ответ зачел?